# THREE.JS - Raycaster performance on OBJ+MTL for collision detection (FirstPersonControls.js)

Tags: javascript, three.js, raycasting

This is the upload of OBJ+MTL(used as texture)

```
var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xf0f0f0, '.$dbData['light_drone'].');
        scene.add(ambientLight);

          var modelloOBJ;
          var fileMTL = "./Uploads/'.$dbData['id'].'/Drone/";
          console.log("fileMTL", fileMTL);
          var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
          mtlLoader.setTexturePath(fileMTL);
          mtlLoader.setPath(fileMTL);
          mtlLoader.load("'.$dbData['file_drone'].'.mtl", function( materials ) {
            materials.preload();
            var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
            loader.setMaterials(materials);
            loader.load(fileMTL+"'.$dbData['file_drone'].'"+".obj", function ( modello ) {
              modelloOBJ = modello;
              modello.rotateOnWorldAxis(new THREE.Vector3(1,0,0), Math.PI * 3 / 2);
              new THREE.Vector3(1,0,0);
              scene.add(modello);
              document.getElementById("ProgressCircle").style.visibility = "hidden";

              modelloOBJ.boundingBox = (new THREE.Box3()).setFromObject(modello);
              camera.lookAt(modelloOBJ.position); //
              var vmax =modelloOBJ.boundingBox.max;
              var vmin = modelloOBJ.boundingBox.min;
              var centroX = ( vmax.x + vmin.x )/2;
              var centroY = vmin.y;
              var centroZ = ( vmax.z + vmin.z )/2;


            },
```

And these are the raycaster(S)

```
  function animate() {

 var delta = clock.getDelta();

 controls.update(delta);

 var vector = new THREE.Vector3(0,-1,0);


vector = camera.localToWorld(vector);
vector.sub(camera.position);

var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(camera.position,vector);

var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children, true);


 if (intersects.length > 0) {

 console.log(intersects[0].distance);

    if(intersects[0].distance<1.21){

    camera.position.y=(camera.position.y+(1.21-intersects[0].distance));

  }

  if(intersects[0].distance>1.36&&intersects[0].distance<1.45){

    camera.position.y=(camera.position.y-(intersects[0].distance-1.215));

  }

}


 var vector1 = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,-1);

vector1 = camera.localToWorld(vector1);
vector1.sub(camera.position);

var raycaster1 = new THREE.Raycaster(camera.position,vector1);

var intersects1 = raycaster1.intersectObjects(scene.children, true);

 if (intersects1.length > 0) {

  console.log(intersects1[0].distance);
 if(intersects1[0].distance<0.3){
  controls.moveForward=false;
  controls.w=false;
 }else{
  controls.w=true;
 }
THREE.Vector3(intersects[0].point.x,intersects[0].point.y,intersects[0].point.z);

}else controls.w=true;

    stats.update(renderer);

console.log(stats.domElement.firstChild.childNodes["0"].innerHTML);
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
    console.log(renderer.info.render.faces);
  }

  animate();
```

PROBLEM: When I add the raycasts to the code, the performances drop considerably. From 60 fps to 20 fps.

Another thing that I tried is this:

```
var l=1;

  function animate() {

     var delta = clock.getDelta();

    controls.update(delta);

if (l%5==0)
{
  var vector = new THREE.Vector3(0,-1,0);

vector = camera.localToWorld(vector);
vector.sub(camera.position);

var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(camera.position,vector);

var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children, true);


 if (intersects.length > 0) {

 console.log(intersects[0].distance);

    if(intersects[0].distance<1.21){

    camera.position.y=(camera.position.y+(1.21-intersects[0].distance));

  }

  if(intersects[0].distance>1.36&&intersects[0].distance<1.45){

    camera.position.y=(camera.position.y-(intersects[0].distance-1.215));

  }

}

var vector1 = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,-1);

vector1 = camera.localToWorld(vector1);
vector1.sub(camera.position);

var raycaster1 = new THREE.Raycaster(camera.position,vector1);

var intersects1 = raycaster1.intersectObjects(scene.children, true);


 if (intersects1.length > 0) {

  console.log(intersects1[0].distance);
 if(intersects1[0].distance<0.3){
  controls.moveForward=false;
  controls.w=false;
 }else{
  controls.w=true;
 }

THREE.Vector3(intersects[0].point.x,intersects[0].point.y,intersects[0].point.z);

}else controls.w=true;
}


    stats.update(renderer);

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
    console.log(renderer.info.render.faces);
   l=l+1;

  }

  animate();
```

In this case they are performed once every five times the animate function is called.

The fps have gone from 20 to 35. But that's inefficient since I use the raycasters for collisions on walls and ground.

The size of the model is less than 20mb. Also, when raycaster isn't working, the model is able to stay on 60fps without any drop.

Remember that I need collision in the model.

Is there a way to improve the performance?
Maybe I should not use raycaster?

P.S. Controls are FirstPersonControls.js, a little bit modified by me.

Comment: `The size of the model is less than 20mb.` How many triangles in your model? Raycaster performs checking of intersection through all the faces/triangles of a mesh.

Comment: Approx 200.000.